# How to set a shaded area around 2d plot curve on a pgfplots figure?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I plotted a 2d figure of a curve but I also want to show variance of the value with a shaded area around the curve line. How can I do it in pgfplots? Here is my current plot.

[image]